# How to add a split text on a spinner on android?

Tags: android, sockets, client, spinner

I create a socket program on android studio. Now when the client receive a message on the server(the message can be vary). The client will split the message and display it on the next activity. I try to display it on an EditText and it works. Now I want to implement it on a Spinner. How can I do it? This is my code for further info.

> MainActivity

```
 android.view.View.OnClickListener ScanOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        SocketHandler.getSocket().SendScan();
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                SocketHandler.setSocket(thread);
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Page2.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }, 3000);
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Page2.class);
        startActivity(i);


    }

};
```

> NexActivity

```
public class Page2 extends Activity {


private EditText a,b,c,d,e,f;


SocketClient thread;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    b = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
    c = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2); 
    d = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3); 
    e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4); 
    f = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5); 


    Thread socketdataThread = new Thread(new SocketdataThread());
    socketdataThread.start();
}


private class SocketdataThread extends Thread {


    @Override
    public void run() {

        String[] response = SocketHandler.getSocket().Socketdata.split("||");


       a.setText(response[0]);
        b.setText(response[1]);
        c.setText(response[2]);
        d.setText(response[3]);
        e.setText(response[4]);
        f.setText(response[5]);



        }

    }
}
```

As you can see I use  String[] response = SocketHandler.getSocket().Socketdata.split("||"); to split the message of the server. the message is varying for example (data1||data2) or (data1||data2||data3) and so on.

> UPDATE: NextActivity

```
public class Page2 extends ActionBarActivity {

private String array_spinner[];
SocketClient thread;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_transaction);

    Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);



    Thread socketServerThread = new Thread(new SocketServerThread());
    socketServerThread.start();
}


private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {


    @Override
    public void run() {

        String[] response = SocketHandler.getSocket().Socketdata.split("||");
        List<String> data = new List<String>();
        for(String resp:response)
        {
            data.add(resp);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] response = SocketHandler.getSocket().Socketdata.split("\\|\\|");
List<String> data = new List<String>();
for(String resp:response)
{
    data.add(resp);
}
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
yourSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: is it possible if I use spinner to get the split message?

Comment: do you want to display the data in spinner?

Comment: sir, I think I'm having a problem on ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);, I'll update my question.